# Hiding upload form without using display: none

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I need to hide a form on my page once a user submits it. Usually I'd just use `display: none` but because of the jQuery file upload plugin I'm using, it will terminate the transfer when the form is invisible. Right now I'm doing this when the form is submitted:

```
// Switch out the form for upload progress
$('#upload-form').animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
    $('#progress-container').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

However, the `#progress-container` div doesn't appear in the place the upload form used to be since the elements are still there and just invisible. In other words, it's shunted underneath them.

Is there a way to properly hide the form and the elements inside it without using `display: none` and have the `#upload-container` div appear in the right place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a brainwave shortly after posting this. Turns out it's not actually that hard. Here's the final code:

```
// Switch out the form for upload progress
$('#upload-form').animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
    $('#upload-form').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#progress-container').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Now the `#progress-container` div floats over the top of the form.

Comment: I see, so you wanted to re-position, and hide at the same time. an animate using the margin top to move up can also do the trick. $(selector).animate({ marginTop: '-=50' },1000); this will re-position an element gently moving it on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SETTING the value of the form's inner html to NULL.

```
$('#upload-form').html('').
```